# Is there a way to get Device twin from ModuleClient using azure iot edge sdk

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-edge

I am developing a custom edge module  using 'ModuleClient' class.
I have to configure a property in device twin and read corresponding value in my edge module.

I know it can be achieved using Device Client class. For that I need the device connection string but I don't have the device connection string handy (since we have thousands of devices we are not encouraging that approach since it creates deployment overhead).

```
AmqpTransportSettings amqpSetting = new AmqpTransportSettings(TransportType.Amqp_Tcp_Only);

var mqttSetting = new MqttTransportSettings(TransportType.Mqtt_Tcp_Only);

TransportSettings[] settings = { amqpSetting };

// Open a connection to the Edge run-time - create from env with transport type (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.moduleclient.createfromenvironmentasync?view=azure-dotnet)
ioTHubModuleClient = await ModuleClient.CreateFromEnvironmentAsync(settings);
```

Comment: Have you consider using module twin (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-module-twins) to pass the information you need instead of device twin?

Comment: Yes, I used it for getting module specific info. I have multiple modules deployed in same device. So have to get device specific info from device twin

Answer (score 1):

There is no options to inbuilt feature to get the device twin from the Iot edge sdk

But there is an work around refer the below link, but its not the recommended approach
https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/631